# mix a noise texture with a normal to make patches

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a forest ground but I want to mix in a grass texture over that. I have tried but found no susses so far. 
My plane are to use a noise texture an after that put on a image texture on top.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use MixRGB node for blending Color and Height images with Noise Texture then put result to Base color and Height inputs of Principled BSDF and Displacement node.

[image]